# Server Object instance creation failed on machine

Tags: arcgis-server

Our GIS Server setup includes 1SOM and 2SOC servers. I am getting this error in Server log. I have tried several settings but none seem to fix the issue, looking for  some feedback on what is the actual fix.

Error1: 
Server Object instance creation failed on machine

Error2: 
Server has no associated SOC machines or all SOC machines are at capacity. Add a SOC machine or change the capacity of the available SOC machines

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 1):

Has this ever worked, or are you just setting things up for the first time now?

Issues I have encountered in the past:

- licensing (you might never even see an error message about licensing, but an expired license can suddenly cause bizarre error messages)
- access - your AGS map service should reference the MXD / MSD via a network share that can also be seen by the SOC servers (e.g. `\\SOM_SERVER\ags_stuff\maps.msd`). Also all data should be accessible via the SOC machine from its path in the map document. If data comes from a database ensure the SOC servers can make the connection, if you're using Shp / FGDB they should also be on a network share

Answer (score 0):

I can only say that I also had the first error and I solved it like [this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Giving_ArcGIS_Server_access_to_folders):